# “no such file or directory:” - how to remove directory from .zprofile

Tags: macos, zsh, terminal.app

I recently uninstalled homebrew from my Mac (macOS 11.2) and since then my terminal opens with the following message:

```
/Users/lukas/.zprofile:6: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
```

I already searched for answers but couldn't find any that explain how to remove the directory from the zprofile.

Comment: Have you tried **editing** the file?

Comment: I have no idea where to find it -- or how to have Finder show it, since it has to be in the Users/Lukas folder...

Comment: That's your home folder. Open the TextEdit app, choose File menu > Open, then in the Open dialog press Command-Shift-H, then Command-Shift-. (aka Command-Shift-Period). That should let you open invisible files in your home folder.

Comment: Thanks, found it. Editing the file solved the problem.